# Ask for credentials during HttpURLConnection without Interrupt the thread

Tags: android, asynchronous, httpurlconnection, credentials

Recently i came across the following issue: I have a webview that loads data in a asynchronous way from a HttpURLConnection, say now that you need from the user to provide credentials so you move on to a basic authentication during your http connection. You do not know if the url needs authentication you just get a 401 error from the response. Is there an appropriate way to pause the Async-Thread so you can ask the user for credentials( px.by a an alert dialog) without stopping the the thread ?

```
 URL requestedUrl = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) requestedUrl.openConnection(proxy);
        if (urlConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            ((HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection)
                      .setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        }
        String userandpass=username+":"+password;

        String basicAuth = "Basic "
                + new String(Base64.encode(
                        userandpass
                                .getBytes(),   Base64.NO_WRAP));
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        result = IOUtil.readFully(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: i did edit the quest with the async task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It pseudo-code. The logic is:

instead of run a singleshoot, you can try n-way. if the login is successfully set notOk. When the while test its execution it will end. Otherwise, asynctask will post a runnable on the UI Thread queue, and the UI Thread will show a dialog. In the Dialog delegate, set the new Username and password, and notify the asynctask to wakeup (`notifyAll()`).

obj has be the same for wait and notifyAll

```
while (notOk) {

   // do your network staff

  if (authOk) {
      notOk= false;
      continue;
  } else {

    runOnTheUiThread(
       run () {
            // a dialog with edit text for username and password.
            // and a button "ok". When user press ok:

           {
              myAsynctAskreference.setUserenameAndPassword(username, password);
               synchronized(obj) {
                   obj.notifyAll();
               }
           }
       }
    )

  }

   synchronized(obj) {
        obj.wait();
   }

}
```